# Getting getCurrentUser() from Sharepoint with Java

Tags: c#, java, web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am trying to find an answer to who i really am.

With Java calling the http://sp.demo/_vti_bin/usergroup.asmx webservice.

My goal is to push Items onto the server, and add a field with the currently logged in user

i am trying this:

```
GetCurrentUserInfoResponse.GetCurrentUserInfoResult result = userPort
        .getCurrentUserInfo();
```

The result has a `List<Object>` in it. The list contains of one Item:

```
result.getContent().get(0)
```

gets to

```
userLoginName = null
```

all help i could find is for C#, but its not applicable.
For retrieving a "normal" List it works, but not for the current user...

Comment: Do you mean Java or JavaScript ? (a lot of people do this mistake so I prefer asking)

Comment: i think i wrote Java... so... i might mean java... and at all, yes, just java - using jdk 7u45. TO solve my issues i played around a little and had a nice talk to our SharePoint admin, who uses C# to connect against the SP WebServices... he told me, that our SP Version won't support the getCurrentUser() WS... so i had to build a  bridge... i am now using the username, found in the System.Environment, ask Sharepoint Webservice "People" (the same as above, but not getCurrentUserInfo() (which returns null here)) getUserInfo(currentUserNameFromEnv) - this works in our setting... but i dislike it..